# Interaction with simulator using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some information from an online simulator, using Python and Selenium, but the interaction is not working. On this website (https://www.wizink.pt/public/creditos#/), I need to click on the plus button (+) to get different values on the simulator but it seems that nothing is working.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.wizink.pt/public/creditos#/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "consent_prompt_submit"))).click()
time.sleep(5)

# click on "+" sign
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]'))).click()
```

I keep getting the error TimeoutException. I also can't get to read the text from TAN (10.00%) or any other text inside the simulator.

I have also tried with beautiful soup, but looks like it can't identify the objects that I am looking for.

Comment: maybe because the elements are inside a shadow root, I can't even find them using CTRL+F on the inspect window (even though I can see them)...

Comment: It's a `<div>` with class "slider-less" or "slider-more".  Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are shadow root elements present. Regular selenium doesn't have special selectors for reaching those directly, but https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase has them. (`pip install seleniumbase`, and run with `python`)

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(browser="chrome") as sb:
    sb.open("https://www.wizink.pt/public/creditos#/")
    sb.click("#consent_prompt_submit")
    sb.wait_for_element("loans-calculator")
    for i in range(6):
        sb.click("loans-calculator::shadow div.slider-more")
    info_css = "loans-calculator::shadow div.simulator_result_info_wrapper"
    print(sb.get_text(info_css))
    sb.sleep(3)
```

Output:

```
Prestação mensal
276,87 €
TAN
10,00%
TAEG
13,0%
```

Although [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) has its own APIs, you can access the raw driver with `sb.driver`.

Comment: Michael, thanks for your help, it worked. But I have another problem. In the same website, if I want to click on the second "plus" sign, related with "Prazo", how can I get it?

Comment: For the second one, use: `sb.click("loans-calculator::shadow #periodRange + div.slider-more")`   --- (`+` is for sibling selector)

Comment: Great! Now I understood the logic behind. Thanks again